# How do I call a root web form from a razor view inside Views folder in MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

I have to call web form located in the project root from the Home/Index view, below project structure:

[image]

I used the next code:

**@Html.Partial("~/WebForm1");**

but got the next error:

The partial view '~/WebForm1' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/WebForm1, any idea please ?

Comment: try `@Html.Partial("WebForm1");`

Comment: @Forty-Two, Not working.

Comment: Please show us your project structure, because "root" sounds a bit strange as does "web form" in a mvc app.

Comment: WebForm1 needs to be in the views folder, either under the controllers sub folder or the shared folder.

Comment: Are you calling MVC action/view or normal ASP.NET Webpage ???

Comment: @Linus Caldwell, mvc conventionnel structure.

Comment: @forty-Two, I have **protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSource ObjectDataSource1;** inside WebForm1.desiner.cs to provide datasource to a report bound to Report viewer inside WebForm1 so that I need to keep it reachable.

Comment: I have no idea what that means

Comment: Razor views don't have a `*.designer.cs` as far as I know. So i guess it's an asp.net web form.

Comment: is webforms a partial view or a webforms file? your mention of **.cs file** indicates that it is a webform. **please share your partial code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for MVC to recognize a Web form is to add its extension "**.aspx**"

@Html.Partial("~/WebForm1.aspx");

Answer (score 0):

To go into the views folder, use

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/pathToYourView");
```

Or place your view in the "Shared" folder to reach the view with

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName");
```

like Forty-Two suggested.

Comment: When I place it inside "Shared" folder I get the next error: Type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' does not have a public property named 'ObjectDataSource'.

Comment: I repeat myself. Please show us your project structure. I don't know what you are trying to do here. I guess you're mixing up mvc and webforms. If so, I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Well, an aspx file is not a view, so I don't think you can render it as a partial.

Comment: Mixing up mvc and webforms is possible, and aspx file is a web page which can be rendered inside a razor view.

Comment: You need .cshtml extension in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/pathToYourView");
```